# JPA changing entity table name on runtime

Tags: jpa

I have two tables with identical schema and data in MySql. one is using InnoDB engine and the other one using MyISAM engine.

I have mapped a JPA entity to InnoDB one and have trigger to update the MyISAM one,
but while querying records I want to use MyISAM version of the table with JPA queries but at the same time I cannot create entity for MyISAM one because it will increase maintenance and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a @MappedSuperclass and have two subclasses for each table.

Otherwise, if you are using EclipseLink you could map to the table you wish to read from, and then override the insert, update and delete operations using a DescriptorCustomizer through the DescriptorQueryManager.